# Why is Bootstrap not respecting my grid layout?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to create a responsive calendar that has 4 events on it, and I want each of these events be shown full-width, **1** on each row (**xs & sm** size) and **2** on each row (**md & lg** size).

I tried using the grid layout on each event but it doesn´t show 2 on each row...

```
<!--Event 1-->     
    <div class="row">
     <div class="div-event">

      <span class="date-event col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1"><span class="num-date-event">22</span>    <br>SEP</span>

      <button class="btn btn-event btn-block col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">Katy's Super Party<br>at her house</button>

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift icon-event col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1" aria-     hidden="true"><span class="text-event"><br>PARTY</span></span>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-1"> 
        <div class="well">
          ...
        </div>
        </div> 

     </div>
   </div>
```

Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong? It would be really appreciated!!

Here is the fiddle of the calendar: http://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/10/

Comment: its because you are organizing each event by row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get it working how you want it, based on your current code, would be to get rid of all of the rows and only use one row containing each event and then add a `col-md-6` class to each event:

```
<!--Event 1-->
<div class="div-event col-md-6">
  <span class="date-event col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1"><span class="num-date-event">22</span>    <br>SEP</span>

  <button class="btn btn-event btn-block col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">Katy's Super Party<br>at her house</button>

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift icon-event col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1" aria-     hidden="true"><span class="text-event"><br>PARTY</span></span>

  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-1"> 
    <div class="well">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/12/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've miss understood how the bootstrap grid works. It is broken into a grid of 12 columns spread across the view port. When you specify a class of col-sm-2 it takes up 2 columns wide. So if you would like 2 html elements to occupy a row, apply a class of col-sm-6 to each of them. They should also be contained within a div with a class of row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-sm-6></span>
    <span class="col-sm-6></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-sm-6></span>
    <span class="col-sm-6></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

That would be a good starting point. It would produce two rows of two items.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap columns are base of 12, which means that the screens width is divided into 12 equal responsive columns. when you want the full width, you use something like `col-md-12`. when you want half width, you use `col-md-6`.  also, when using `row`, that groups all the columns with in.  since you want the events to be responsive and "pair up" in twos when it is a large or mid size screen, you need to put all events into a single `row` instead of sectioning them off in multiple rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/329/

this should get you started on what you need to do with your current structure

```css
.event {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="event col-md-6 col-sm-12">EVENT</div>
        <div class="event col-md-6 col-sm-12">EVENT</div>
        <div class="event col-md-6 col-sm-12">EVENT</div>
        <div class="event col-md-6 col-sm-12">EVENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you should probably read the documentation on bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid